# is there a way to call a Component's function from click function of Chartjs

Tags: angular, typescript, function, scope, chart.js

how can i call a function of my Component, from my onclick function of my chartjs

```
export class ReportesComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor( public _router: Router ,private data:ReporteService) {}
  this.chart = new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
   labels: this.barCharLabels,
   datasets: [
    { 
      data : this.dataCharCartera,
      label:'Cartera',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(232,95,95)'
    },
    { 
      data : this.dataChar,
      label:'Penetracion',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(95,145,232)'
    }
   ]
    },
  options: {
      legend : {
        display: true
      },
      responsive : true,
      scales : {
        xAxes :[{
          ticks:{
            beginAtZero: true
          }
        }]
      },
      onClick: function (e) {
        var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
        if (element.length) {
           console.log(element[0]._view.label)
        }
        console.log(element);

      },
    }
 });
 }
 Showtest(e) : void {
 console.log(e)
 this._router.navigate(['/Menu/Informacion']);//
 }

}
```

i want to call my function Showtest and get the element value with my onClick function that is inside my chartjs, Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can bind. But chartjs plugin is element based. So you need to write a directive to implement to apply any jQuery or element based approach.

Here is the solution for your question. 
Here the trick is assign a component this to some other variable and access it inside a the chartjs click function. After that you can pass any data you want.

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = this.mychart.nativeElement; 
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    let $this = this;
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'bar',

      data: ...,
      options: {
          legend : {
            display: true
          },
          responsive : true,
          scales : {
            xAxes :[{
              ticks:{
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            }]
          },
          onClick: function (e) {
            debugger;
            var element = this.getElementAtEvent(e);
            if (element.length) {
               console.log(element[0]._view.label)
            }
            $this.Showtest(e, this, element);
          },
          //onClick: this.Showtest.bind(this),
        }
    });
  }

  Showtest(event, chart, element) : void {
    debugger;
  }
```

Comment: this is working but now im not getting the event of my chart

Comment: i was getting [ChartElement] but now MouseEvent {isTrusted: true, screenX: 229, screenY: 206, clientX: 229, clientY: 135, …} with my console.log(e)

Comment: can you post some fiddle? I will check that

Comment: Use this link to create your sample .. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js

Comment: u can click the chart and inspect with and without ur solution and u ll see the difference  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-chart-js-gkcel2?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Updated please check

Comment: thas working, thank you so much for your time and help